# How to display a text at the bottom left of the Image

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a text at the bottom left if the image to be like as the below figure:

[image]

and this the below code is related:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/city.dart';

class ProvinceItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final city = Provider.of<City>(context, listen: false);
    // final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        onTap: () => {},
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                offset: const Offset(2.5, 2.5),
                blurRadius: 16,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
              city.cityImage,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have just create a list of Grid widget and as every list of grid item have a grid item just shown like the previous code...

as I need the best suggestion for this Grid item as it only contains just an image and a text with some of shadows..

Comment: Use a Stack widget

Comment: use image:DecorationImage inside BoxDexoration, image with be used a background this way, in child you may use Text widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack widget will do the trick for you.

```
    Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            onTap: () => {},
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                    offset: const Offset(2.5, 2.5),
                    blurRadius: 16,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  city.cityImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 20),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Text',,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```